# The Op-Amps don't work correctly for this circuit [Thermocouple]

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, thermocouple, non-inverting

I'm trying to connect a thermocouple to an Op-Amp to amplify the output of a thermocouple. this is the circuit:

[image: figure1]

Also for R17 I put a 5k09 resistor instead of 6k8 and for R18, 1k032 and for R19, 366k and my circuit doesn't has the P1.

The Op-Amp is LM358N. when I use a potentiometer for the input(HEATER+) to test and check the circuit, everything work correctly but when I connect the circuit to the heater(or thermocouple because it's a soldering iron), the Op-Amp get freezed! :) I mean it just show a little and constant amount in the output (while the input is changing). why? something must be wrong.

Please consider that this circuit should work and when I measure the positive of the Op-Amp, there is the voltage as I expected.

For supply I use [this(24V 5A Switching Power Supply)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00SVLK5PU) and [this Buck Converter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008BHAOQO) to make 5v for circuit and before the buck converter put a 470uf electrolytic capacitor and after it put a 10uf electrolytic capacitor and 100nf ceramic capacitor.

I get the circuit from [this project](http://dangerousprototypes.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=5264&start=180#p58264). here is the schematic:

[image: figure2]

**What have I done so far?**

I have changed my Op-Amp to some other but I had the same problem. even with a perfect Op-Amp like AD8572ARZ-REEL7. it's an auto-zero drift rail to rail I/O Op-Amp and a good choice for such a job. I have changed 4 Op-Amp to amplify the output of thermo for this job but still the same problem!

I have changed the supply to a 5v battery(because I thought there is noise in the supply) and I saw that the output of the Op-Amp start to changing but the changes was a small amount between 32mv and 13mv.

A bit information [from this post](http://dangerousprototypes.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=5264#p50627) about this type of soldering iron and its tips:

> T12 have thermocouple in series with the heater with a voltage of
>   around 9mV at 450 degrees celsius, so the voltage to the heater must
>   be turned off to measure the voltage of the thermocouple. Don't
>   measure the resistance of T12. It is pointless to use it when a
>   thermocouple is already available, and is far more precise than
>   resistance.
>
> I have made a controller for T12 myself. Here's how it works:
>   - the 24V AC from transfomer is rectified but not filtered
>   - this rectified 24V AC is the power to the T12, and is switched on and off for a millisecond on every half period of the AC, using P
>   channel MOSFET.
>   - when the voltage is turned off, the voltage of the thermocouple is available at t12 terminals, so it can be measured by an ADC in MCU
>   - the MCU controls the heating using slightly modified PID algothitm, regulating how many mains periods the heater is turned on, and how
>   many mains periods it is turned off.

**Edit:** I changed the supply to this:

[image: figure3]

[Breadboard Power Supply with 3.3v & 5v Outputs](http://pcboard.ca/store/breadboard-power-supply-with-3-3v-and-5v-outputs.html)

And applied the heat and I got the output as I expected!! then the problem is the switching supply! any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's a thermocouple and not a thermistor or RTD?

Comment: @Andyaka Hi Andy, Yes, T12 tips have thermocouple in series with the heater as sparkybg in that post has said. Why do you think that could be a thermistor or RTD?

Comment: I'm asking because your results seem to indicate a passive sensor like an RTD or thermistor.

Comment: Are you sure the opamps are within their linear region? Does it work better with bipolar supplies to the opamps?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Hi Brian, take a look at this post: http://dangerousprototypes.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=5264&start=270#p60879 as you can see this guy has made his soldering iron with this Op-Amp and it's working very good. this Op-Amp should work very well. alone problem that you will have when using this Op-Amp is the temp drift.

Comment: You have a lot of gain, is it possible that noise is causing your op-amp to sit at one of the rails?  What is the actual output voltage?  It looks like you're running the op-amp single supply?

Comment: I don't know what you want me to consider?

Comment: Maybe a grounding issue. Your schematic does not show the connections of the power supply and heater power supply. This kind of thermocouple is probably non-standard base-metal- a wire welded to one side of a Nichrome heater winding. Actually measure the input voltage with the T/C connected (relative to ground) and see what it is.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Grounding!? also my switching power supply has an Earth input/output but I didn't connect it to the Earth because my house doesn't has Earth in socket wall.

Comment: I'm not familiar with AC wiring in Iran but an interesting test would be if you have a USB power bank or a laptop try connecting that to the USB power connector and see if it still works with the linear supply. When your PC and soldering iron are both connected to mains maybe the grounds are coupled somehow and that's why your battery based solutions don't work. I think that's what Spehro means and the iron and your circuit will need to share a common ground, but that might need some care when dealing with mains.

Comment: @PeterJ Hi Peter, What's up, man? :) as you can see my 24v switching supply has two + and -. I connected one of them to buck module to supply the circuit and connected another + to the soldering iron to turn it on/off. when I measure the output of the Op-Amp (when I didn't share the both ground), I get +25mv at the output and when I share the both ground together I get -29mv at the output. another point is that both value is constant(a bit oscillate) even when I apply heat.

Comment: The LM2596 based DC-DC converter module you used first has a potentiometer to adjust the output voltage? Did you adjust it after connecting to the rest of the design?

Comment: @asndre Yes. it's 7v5.

Comment: You wrote "For supply I use ... this Buck Converter to make 5v...". Why is it 7.5 V now instead of 5.0 V?

Comment: @asndre Yes, because I have used a linear regulator(L7805) to regulate the current because I thought that the Buck is making noise. I just changed the op-amp to tlc272cp and it's working. I don't know why. the only difference I can see is that earlier the Op-Amps was simple(I mean they had BJT transistor) but tlc272cp has LinCMOS technology. also tlc272cp is better for this project. but still I'm curious to know why it didn't with those Op-Amps?